# Linking PartialView to View returns System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I looked up everywhere and tried multiple solutions but none of them would work. In my MVC website, I have a cart section and a checkout section. I want to make it so inside my checkout section, i have a small cart section to show the cart.

This is my partial view _CartItems.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ArrowDefenseSystems.Models.Cart>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Your Cart";
}
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="itemInfo row">
            <img class="col-md-3" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/" + @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productImage))" height="100px">
            <div class="CartItemText col-md-9">
                <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productName)</h3>
                <i>$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productPrice)</i><br>
                Quantity : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantityChosen)<br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    }
}
```

When I launch the Partial View by itself, it shows the items fine and everything runs correctly.

This is how I'm linking the partial view to the view Checkout.cshtml

```
@model ArrowDefenseSystems.Models.ParentViewModel
...
...
@Html.Partial("_CartItems", Model.Cart)
```

When I run this code i get the following error on the code above:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.
```

ParentViewModel:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
   public Checkout Checkout { get; set; }
   public Cart Cart { get; set; }
}
```

Checkout Controller (theres more but its unnecessary):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult _CartItems()
{
  return PartialView(db.Carts.ToList());
}
public ActionResult Checkout()
{

   return View();

}
```

I've tried many solutions but all return the same error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding here: `@Html.Partial("_CartItems", Model.Cart)` will not call your `_CartItems()` action. Instead, it will create a new instance of the `_CartItems.cshtml` partial view, and use your `Model.Cart` parameter as it's `Model`.

In this case, there are two problems:

- `_CartItems.cshtml` is expecting a model with a type of `IEnumerable<ArrowDefenseSystems.Models.Cart>`, whereas you are passing it a model with a type of `Cart` (via the `Model.Cart` parameter)
- `Model.Cart` is not being instantiated in your `Checkout` action

So, to fix this, you should first change your `ParentViewModel` to be:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
   public Checkout Checkout { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
}
```

Then, update your `Checkout` action to be:

```
public ActionResult Checkout()
{
   var viewModel = new ParentViewModel
   {
       Carts = db.Carts.ToList()
   }

   return View(viewModel);
}
```

And change your usage of `Model.Cart` to `Model.Carts` (due to the rename above)

After that, you can remove your `_CartItems` action as it is no longer used.

Comment: I changed it to @Html.Partial("_CartItems", Model.CartEnum) and added to the Model public IEnumerable<Cart> CartEnum { get; set; } but I still get the same error.

Comment: Is `CartEnum` being instantiated in your `Checkout()` action? (see the second code block)

Comment: That worked, thank you very much, ive been at this for hours!